# Volley sends null parameters to server when using post method

Tags: java, php, android, wordpress

I used volley for connect to Wordpress site. It worked correctly .But Volley send null parameters to server When the PHP is updated to PHP2.7.

MyPHP Code is :

```php
<?php
    require_once("../wp-load.php");
    require_once("class.aesCrypt.php");
    $tellenc = $_POST['username'];
    $passenc = $_POST['pass'];
    $serialdiviceenc= $_POST['serial'];

    $tell= $tellenc;
    $pass= $passenc;
    $serialdivice=$serialdiviceenc;
    $username=$tell.$serialdivice;
    var_dump($username);
    $output= [];
    $user_id = username_exists( $username );
    ...
    ?>
```

I cheacked My php code in Postman like above. It got null parameters from Post Method .

```php
<?php
    require_once("../wp-load.php");
    require_once("class.aesCrypt.php");
    $tellenc = $_POST['username'];
    $passenc = $_POST['pass'];
    $serialdiviceenc= $_POST['serial'];
   ...
   ?>
```

When my PHP code like above, it is work correctly in postman App.

But With Volley In both cases it gets null parameters. I very googling but I cant fixed it. How can fix it ?for now My problem is volley that send null parameters to server .

And My Java Code Is:

```java
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
flag=false;
String regurl = G.BaseURl+"/AndroidLoginUser.php";
Response.Listener<String> listener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {}
};
Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
};
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, regurl, listener, errorListener) {
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("username", txtUsername.getText().toString());
        params.put("pass", txtpass.getText().toString());
        params.put("serial",G.deviceSerial);
        return params;
    }
};
request.setShouldCache(false);
AppSingleton.getInstance(context).getRequestQueue().getCache().clear();
request.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
    @Override
    public int getCurrentTimeout() {
        return 50000;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
        return 50000;
    }

    @Override
    public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {}
});
AppSingleton.getInstance(context).addToRequestQueue(request);
```

Comment: Please use retrofit it's better than volley https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-retrofit-http-library/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing ' with " in PHP code. :D

```
$tellenc = $_POST["username"];
$passenc = $_POST["pass"];
$serialdiviceenc= $_POST["serial"];
```